# Argv - String into Integer

Tags: python, argv

I'm pretty new at python and I've been playing with argv. I wrote this simple program here and getting an error that says :

> TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str

```
from sys import argv

file_name, num1, num2 = argv
int(argv[1])
int(argv[2])
def addfunc(num1, num2):
    print "This function adds %d and %d" % (num1, num2)
    return num1 + num2

addsum = addfunc(num1, num2)
print "The final sum of addfunc is: " + str(addsum)
```

When I run filename.py 2 2, does argv put 2 2 into strings? If so, how do I convert these into integers?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`sys.argv` is indeed a list of strings. Use the `int()` function to turn a string to a number, provided the string *can* be converted.

You need to *assign* the result, however:

```
num1 = int(argv[1])
num2 = int(argv[2])
```

or simply use:

```
num1, num2 = int(num1), int(num2)
```

You did call `int()` but ignored the return value.

Answer (score 6):

Assign the converted integers to those variables:

```
num1 = int(argv[1])  #assign the return int to num1
num2 = int(argv[2])
```

Doing just:

```
int(argv[1])
int(argv[2])
```

won't affect the original items as `int` returns a new `int` object, the items inside `sys.argv` are not affected by that.

Yo modify the original list you can do this:

```
argv[1:] = [int(x) for x in argv[1:]]
file_name, num1, num2 = argv  #now num1 and num2 are going to be integers
```

Answer (score 1):

Running `int(argv[1])` doesn't actually change the value of `argv[1]` (or of `num1`, to which it is assigned).

Replace this:

```
int(argv[1])
int(argv[2])
```

With this:

```
num1 = int(num1)
num2 = int(num2)
```

and it should work.

The int(..), str(...) etc functions do not modify the values passed to them. Instead, they *return* a reinterpretation of the data as a different type.